How do I select a single hole in a hole feature that contains multiple holes?
 public void MultipleSelection(string childNodeValue1, string childNodeValue2)
 {
     try
     {
         SldWorks swApp = Utility.ConnectToSolidWorks();
         ModelDoc2 swModel = (ModelDoc2)swApp.ActiveDoc;
         swModel.ClearSelection2(true);

         string targetComponentName1 = childNodeValue1.Split(new[] { " - " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
         string targetFeature1 = childNodeValue1.Split(new[] { " - " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

         string targetComponentName2 = childNodeValue2.Split(new[] { " - " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
         string targetFeature2 = childNodeValue2.Split(new[] { " - " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

         // Use LINQ to find the Vector3D object with the specified component name and feature
         var result1 = pointList.FirstOrDefault(v => v.ComponentName == targetComponentName1 && v.Feature == targetFeature1);
         // Use LINQ to find the Vector3D object with the specified component name and feature
         var result2 = pointList.FirstOrDefault(v => v.ComponentName == targetComponentName2 && v.Feature == targetFeature2);

         bool status1 = swModel.Extension.SelectByID2(result1.Feature + @"@" + result1.ComponentName + @"@" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(swModel.GetPathName()), "BODYFEATURE", 0, 0, 0, true, 1, null, 0);


         bool status2 = swModel.Extension.SelectByID2(result2.Feature + @"@" + result2.ComponentName + @"@" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(swModel.GetPathName()), "BODYFEATURE", 0, 0, 0, true, 0, null, 0);


         swModel.ViewZoomToSelection();
         IModelView activeView = (IModelView)swModel.ActiveView;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }

 }

I selected a hole feature by ("feature name" @ "component name" @ "assembly name"), but now I want to select a single hole in this hole feature. How do I modify my code?
